# Is Hessian symetric for the function $\phi : X \to \Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\phi : X \to \Bbb R$ be  a $C^2$ function.

My question:

Is $\nabla^2 \phi (\bar{x})$ , the Hessian of $\phi$ at point $\bar{x} \in X , $ symmetric  operator?
(as it is really symmetric matrix in case $X$ is finite dimension)

I feel like the general answer is NO in arbitrary Banach space but still I don't have a counter example for it but I suspect it is true in Hilbert spaces. 
Note that $\nabla \phi (\bar{x} ) \in X^* $ and $ \nabla^2 \phi (\bar{x} ) \in L ( X, X^* ) $ and $ ( \nabla^2 \phi (\bar{x}) )^* \in L ( X^{**} , X^* ) $. So in case question makes sense  we have to consider the setting space be a reflexive Banach space.

By symetricity  of $\nabla^2 \phi(\bar{x})$ I mean

$$\nabla^2 \phi(\bar{x})=\nabla^2 \phi(\bar{x})^*$$

Comment: Also asked on MO: [Is Hessian symetric for the function $ϕ:X→\Bbb R$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282625)

Comment: Red shoes: I see you left some comment on the MO copy (which is deleted at the moment), but did not have enough time to read the comment before the deletion (still I got the ping). In case it was addressed to me, feel free to repost it here - if some reply from me is required, I can respond here.

Comment: Nevermind ..  was not important.. just wanted you to delete your comment here , and then I would delete that post in over fellow...

Comment: The associated bilinear form is symmetric under permutation of its arguments as a consequence of the mean value theorem on Banach spaces. See Lemma 9.21 on page 254 of Arbogast and Bona, "Methods of Applied Mathematics", https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/arbogast/appMath08c.pdf

Comment: @NickAlger  Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Nonliteral quotes from *Calcul Differéntiel* by Henry Cartan.

1. Let be $E$, $F$ Banach spaces, $U\subset E$ open If $f:U \longrightarrow F$ is two times differentiable at $a\in U$, $D^2f(a)$ (second differential) is an element of the space $L(E,L(E,F))$ (space of continuous linear functions from $E$ to...).
2. There is a canonical isomorphism (as Banach spaces, not only as vector spaces)
   $$L(E,L(E,F))\approx L_2(E,F)$$
   where the RHS is the space of bilinear continuous functions $E\times E\to F$ (Section 1.9).
3. Via the previous identification, $D^2f(a)$, now considered as an element of $L_2(E,F)$, is symmetric (Theorem 5.3.1).

Comment: My function is real valued, and by symmetric I  mean self adjoint !  Not actually symmetric  bilinear ...

Comment: @Redshoes As you seem to be aware in the question, directly comparing an operator and its adjoint does not make sense in the Banach space case, since they are functions that map between different spaces. Symmetry of the bilinear form is one way to define symmetry, though there are others. See, for example, the answers here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154474/self-adjointness-for-banach-spaces

Comment: @NickAlger   Thank you ! But I think "being symmetric" in sense of symmetric bilinear (like the lemma in the book you pointed out) implies self- adjoint when the space is Hilbert ... what do you think?